# How does the Build Pipeline Plugin relate to the Jenkins 2 Pipeline Plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Currently, I use the Build Pipeline Plugin to orchestrate the delivery of my code through the different environments:

1. Build the code and execute unit tests
2. Manually deploy to the development environment
3. Automatically execute tests on the development environment
4. Manually release the software and put the version number to the released version.
5. Manually deploy to the integration test environment by downloading the artefact from a repository, based on the version put by the release build.
6. Manually deploy to ...

With Jenkins 2.0 comes the Pipeline plugin. But how do these two plugins relate to each other?

Should I migrate to the latest plugin? The things I seem to miss from the Jenkins 2 Pipeline plugin:

- Manually trigger a stage. I can wait for an input, but it does not seem to be so elegant
- Restart a stage to retrigger a deployment. This does not seem possible.
- Visibility into the parameters that were used to trigger a stage, e.g. the version number of the software that was deployed.

Am I missing the point here? Should the two of them be combined? Or how are you approaching a pipeline like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current state of Jenkins 2 pipelines you are correct to state all the 'missing features' you listed.

One of the advantages of the Jenkins 2 pipeline plugin is that rather than chaining together a series of jobs as with the Build Pipeline Plugin, your entire pipeline is 1 'job', which makes user administration much easier IMO.

The other advantage of Jenkins 2 pipelines would be 'configuration as code', so you can track changes to your pipeline as you would any other file in version control.

Jenkins 2 pipelines are very much the new 'hotness', and there's many plugins implementing compatability day after day.

Once the new UI becomes production ready, I'd imagine that the old build pipeline plugin will begin to be deprecated.

Also you should be aware that the Build Pipeline plugin is not maintained by the Jenkins or CloudBees teams as far as I know, whereas Jenkins 2 pipelines are.

Would I recommend migrating now? No, I personally still don't consider the Jenkins 2 pipelines mature enough for deployment to production in an organisation. I'd stay to stick with what you know for now while you wait for the Jenkins 2 Pipeline ecosystem to mature.

My reasoning I gave in a blog post a few weeks ago ([read more here if you want](https://reidweb.com/2017/02/01/what-ive-learnt-about-jenkins-pipelines/), but I've extracted out the 'weaknesses' here for you):

- There are still plenty of plugins that I and many others will consider 'core to their CI pipeline' missing full or partial support for pipelines.
- The lack of 'per-project-configuration' in pipelines for many plugins. e.g. Slack - the current implementation 'assumes' that all Jenkins 2 Pipeline projects should be communicated to the same Slack channel/team - whereas you may want to have multiple Slack teams configured. There are multiple other plugins like this.
- At present the documentation of Jenkins 2 Pipelines is very limited, though this is improving.